# Firing individual events of dynamically created controls in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I have created a code for creating a group of controls at run time in windows application.
I am trying to get individual click event of buttons but this is working for all the buttons.

the code I am trying is

```
 public partial class Employee_PayHeads_add : Form
{


    private TextBox newTxtBox = new TextBox();
    private Button newBtnAdd = new Button();
    private ComboBox newCombohead = new ComboBox();

    private int txtBoxStartPosition = 150;
    private int btnAddStartPosition = 240;
    private int comboheadStartPosition = 10;


    private int txtBoxStartPositionV = 25;
    private int btnAddStartPositionV = 25;
    private int comboheadStartPositionV = 25;

    public Employee_PayHeads_add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox newTxtBox = new TextBox();
        Button newBtnAdd = new Button();
        ComboBox newCombohead = new ComboBox();

        newBtnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        newBtnAdd.Text = "Remove";
        newBtnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(btnAddStartPosition, txtBoxStartPositionV);
        newBtnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 25);

        newTxtBox.Text = "";
        newTxtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(txtBoxStartPosition, btnAddStartPositionV);
        newTxtBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 40);

        newCombohead.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(comboheadStartPosition, comboheadStartPositionV);

        panel1.Controls.Add(newBtnAdd);
        panel1.Controls.Add(newTxtBox);
        panel1.Controls.Add(newCombohead);


        txtBoxStartPositionV += 30;
        btnAddStartPositionV += 30;
        comboheadStartPositionV += 30;

        newBtnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);


         }

    void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = "Hello Gagan";
    }
```

I want to get the click event of individual buttons, suppose I have to display the text in the respective textbox with the button on Label1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Issue is you can't raise event Dynamically right.?

Comment: You want to have a method for each button click event? I dont really understand you

Comment: Is that the Label is placed in panel1 or not?

Comment: Actually I have to send the value in textbox in database on click of the button besides it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are willing to do. Anyhow looking the above code, you might have a quite number of controls in series (Button followed by Textbox and then ComboBox) all are added into the Panel through button1_Click(). If that is the case, follow this sequence:

1. From the handler, you will know the index of the Button in the Panel.
2. The next index refers to the TextBox control.
3. Get that TextBox and set the Text.

   ```
   void bu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Type type = panel1.Controls[(panel1.Controls.IndexOf(sender as Button)) + 1].GetType();
       if(type == typeof(TextBox))
       {
           TextBox tb = (TextBox) panel1.Controls[
                           (panel1.Controls.IndexOf(sender as Button)) + 1];
           tb.Text = "Hello Gagan";
       }
   }
   ```